# how can I solve raise NotImplementedError in Pythone3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, websocket, tornado

I have a file called app.py. there is a class called **EchoWebSocket**. under the **EchoWebSocket**, I wrote a function called **on_message**. I am getting a JSON like data here, message = {type: 'login', name: 'xyz'} from the javascript frontend. I declared a global variable called **data**. Now I want to parse the message and stored it in the global variable called **data** through a exception handling block. But I am getting an error called ** raise NotImplementedError**. Below is my python code, I am new in these technology, please help me to solve these issue.

/app.py

```
class EchoWebSocket(WebSocketHandler):

  clients = []

def open(self):
    logging.info('WebSocket opened from %s', self.request.remote_ip)
    EchoWebSocket.clients.append(self)

def on_message(self, message):
    #logging.info('got message from %s: %s', self.request.remote_ip, message)
    logging.info('message %s:', message)
    global data
    try:
      data = JSON.parse(message)
    except MyError as e:
      logging.info("Invalid JSON")
      data = {}
```

/Error

```
[I 170404 11:35:30 web:1971] 304 GET / (127.0.0.1) 1.58ms
[I 170404 11:35:30 web:1971] 304 GET /static/js/client.js (127.0.0.1) 3.28ms
[E 170404 11:35:34 websocket:415] Uncaught exception in /ws
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 412, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 255, in on_message
        raise NotImplementedError
    NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Your `try...except` block is indented with 2 spaces which is very likely to cause SyntaxError. Python code is always indented with 4 spaces. NotImplementedError means that some part of a package's functionality is, em, not implemented (not written). If it's a class's method, you can redefine it so it will work.

Comment: Four-space indentation is purely a matter of convention. There's no syntax problem with using two,  just a potential human-reader-confusion problem.

Comment: Two spaces or four spaces is fine as long as you're consistent, but there's a bigger problem: the `def open` and `def on_message` lines aren't indented at all. If that's how it is in your real code (and not a mistake when you copied it in to stack overflow), then that's the problem. As written here, you're defining module-level functions `open` and `on_message`, when you need to be defining them as methods in the `EchoWebSocketHandler` class.

Answer (score 0):

May be you mast implement on_close method in your subclass

```
def on_close(self):
    print("WebSocket closed")
```